# ELMAH does not log errors to SQL Server on production server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, elmah

Elmah works perfectly fine on my local web personal web server. However, it does not log any error to the same SQL Server on the production server even though I'm connecting to the same SQL server. When I access the elmah.axd, it shows the page fine but no error has been logged. Any help is much appreciated.

**Web.Config File**

```
<configuration>
     <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="myAdvanceApp" value="myAdvanceApp"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="advanceConnStr" connectionString="Data Source=gans;Initial Catalog=Advancement;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myUser;Password=myPass" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="myADConnString" connectionString="LDAP://myDomain.com/ou=useraccounts,DC=myDomain,DC=com"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="32768" />
    <!--<authentication mode="Windows"/>-->
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" timeout="30" loginUrl="Admin/Login.aspx" />
    </authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="myApp">
      <providers>
        <add name="myADProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionUsername="myDomain-mail\mybldap" connectionPassword="mypassword)" connectionStringName="myADConnString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <!--<customErrors mode="Off" />-->
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
        <add assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor" tagPrefix="cc1"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <elmah>
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="advanceConnStr" applicationName="myAdvanceApp" />
    <security allowRemoteAccess="true" />
  </elmah>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <location path="elmah.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="myUserName" />
        <deny users="*,?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
      </location>
     </configuration>
```

Comment: Show the relevant sections from your web.config file.

Comment: Thanks. Now try converting it to save to an XML file or in memory. This will let you know if the errors are even making their way to Elmah.

Comment: It might me a dumb question, but did you remember to execute the ELMAH SQL scripts on your production environment.

Comment: Yes, I did. What is odd is that it works perfectly fine on the developer machine.